# Spark Streaming Saving data to MySQL with foreachRDD() in Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, spark-streaming

Spark Streaming Saving data to MySQL with `foreachRDD()` in Scala

Please, can somebody give me a functional example about saving an Spark Streaming to MySQL DB using `foreachRDD()` in Scala. I have below code but it's not working. I just need a simple example, not sintaxis or theory.

Thank you!

```
package examples
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import StreamingContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode  
object StreamingToMysql {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NetworkWordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val hiveCtx= new HiveContext(sc)
    import hiveCtx.implicits._
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/Streaming/logs")    
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1))
    val df = rdd.toDF()
    val split = lines.map(line => line.split(",")  )
    val input = split.map(x => x(0))
    input.foreachRDD { rdd =>
                 if (rdd.take (1).size == 1) {
                     rdd.foreachPartition { iterator =>
                         iterator.foreach {
                          val connectionProperties = new Properties()
                          connectionProperties.put("user", "root")
                          connectionProperties.put("password", "admin123")
                          iterator.write.mode("append")
                        .jdbc("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.8:3306/hadoopguide", "topics", connectionProperties) 
                         }
                 }
             }    
    }
    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.put("user", "root")
    connectionProperties.put("password", "admin123")
    df.write.mode("append")
  .jdbc("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.8:3306/hadoopguide", "topics", connectionProperties)    
    println("Done")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()      
  }   
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting?

Comment: @RahulSharma what are you talking about?? This is **Spark** that question is generic scala. Please remove your "possible duplicate" comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write data from Spark Streaming to an external system, you can use the high-level dataframes API or the low-level RDD. In the code above, both approaches are mixed and do work.

Assuming that you know the structure of the incoming data in Spark Streaming, you can create a Dataframe out of each RDD and use the Dataframe API to save it:

First, create a schema for the data:

```
case class MyStructure(field: Type,....)
```

then, apply the schema to the incoming stream:

```
val structuredData = dstream.map(record => MyStructure(record.field1, ... record.fieldn))
```

Now use the `foreachRDD` to transform each RDD in the DStream into a Dataframe and use the DF API to save it:

```
// JDBC writer configuration
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", "root")
connectionProperties.put("password", "*****")

structuredData.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val df = rdd.toDF() // create a dataframe from the schema RDD      
  df.write.mode("append")                        
    .jdbc("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.8:3306/hadoopguide", "topics", connectionProperties) 
}
```